# Asyncio, asyncio.sleep(5) sends every variable after 5 sec and not one after the other

Tags: python, python-asyncio, sleep

Is there a solution to the asyncio.sleep() function. I am sending multiple commands to the func "async def send" as "command" and it should send one after the other. It only sends one and after 5 sec the rest.

**EDIT:**

```
async def send(self, command, count):

         for x in range(count):
            await self.ws.send(command)
            lb1.insert(END, command)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

This is my func that passes the values:

```
def sending():
        command = entry.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
        p = command.split('@')
        count = 0
        for x in p:
            print(f'Sent -> {x}')
            asyncio.ensure_future(echo.send(x, count))
            count+=1

btn2.config(command=sending)
```

I am expecting:
for example: 4 input commands, first one gets sent out and the delay starts for 5 sec and the secound one should be sent out -> delay 5 sec -> ...

**FINAL EDIT:**

```
async def send(self, command):

    p = command.split('@')

    for x in p:
        await self.ws.send(x)
        lb1.insert(END, x)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Now it works :) I found my mistake

```
def sending():
    command = entry.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    print(f'Sent -> {command}')
    asyncio.ensure_future(echo.send(command))
```

Comment: If you intended this to loop, then you should have included a loop.  ;)

Comment: when `count` is 0 `send` won't do anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you intend:

```
async def send(self, command, count):
    for i in range(count):
        await self.ws.send(command)
        lb1.insert(END, command)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

However, the use of `insert` makes me think this is a tkinter app.  If that is correct, then this is the wrong approach.  Nothing will get updated until this function returns and gets back to the main loop.  You main need to use `tk.after` instead.

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you for the answer. My code above was exaclty like yours (I was already doubting the loop out of frustration, hence the garbage code up there ;)) but as you said I am using a tkinter gui in which the await asyncio.sleep() function is not doing what I thought it would do.
I actually have a workaround that allows me to use asyncio with tkinter.
Could you explain me what tk.after does in this context and how to implement it?

Comment: `tk.after` queues up an event to have a function called after a certain number of milliseconds.  It's handled by the main loop, so it's a normal part of the tk processing.  That's the proper way to do periodic processing in a GUI app, not an infinite loop with sleeps.